# Selenium Webdriver - Appeand

Tags: loops, selenium-webdriver

I am new to Selenium Web Driver and I have a problem. I have a list and need to click on each item from the list and send it for further processing. Items will remove from the list once they send successfully. Only showing some count of items in list, once all items removed from the list then click on an button which will append rest items in the list. I need to automate this process and want to run this process in loop.

Comment: sounds good.  and what have you tried so far Manoj?  and what language are you using

Answer (score 0):

You didn't post any code. So I'm assuming the elements can be found with the same selector multiple times.

```
     List<WebElement> list = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("listelement"));
         int  Theamountofelements= list.size();
         for (int i=Theamountofelements-1; i>=0; i--) {
          //Here we are looping the opposite way. We wanna start from. 
//Assuming that the elements disappear after accepting them
     List<WebElement> Listclick=driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("listelement"));


            Listclick.get(i).click();

       }
```